# Pass data from a template tag to a django view

Tags: python, django

I'd like to pass a parameter with data, like category_id=2 from my template to the view.  Here is how I think it should work (which obviously doesn't)...

The view

```
def category_detail(request, category_id):
    return_list = Category.objects.filter(category_id=category_id)
    return render(request,
                  'expense_list.html',
        {
            'expense_list' : return_list
        })
```

HTML in the template:

```
<a href="{% url 'category_detail' category_id=2 %}">Blah</a>
```

Urls file:

```
url(r'^detail/(?P<category_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.category_detail, name='category_detail'),
```

Comment: What "obviously doesn't" work? What happens with this code? How does that differ from what you expect? What errors do you get?

Comment: @DanielRoseman had a typo in the url template.  Everything above worked (as I initially expected it to).  Thanks in any case for taking time on my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a list of urls by doing something like:

```
{% for category in expense_list.all %}
    <a href="{% url 'app_label:view_name' category_id=category.id %}">{{ category.name }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Where app_label is the label/name of the app and view_name in this case category_detail.